# React context API when wrapped around the main app component in index.js file it's display nothing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, mern, react-context

I am learning about context API.  **reducer.js**:

```js
export const initialState = {
    user: null,
    playlist: [],
    playing: false,
    item: null
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    console.log(action);

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SET_USER': 
            return {
                ...state,
                user: action.user
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
    
}

export default reducer;
```

**DataLayer.js**:

```js
import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer} from "react";

export const DataLayerContext = createContext();

export const DataLayer = ({initialState, reducer, children}) => {
    <DataLayerContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </DataLayerContext.Provider>
};
```

now I am wrapping my App component around it in the index.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { DataLayer } from './DataLayer';
import reducer, { initialState } from './reducer';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
 // <React.StrictMode>
  <DataLayer initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
    <App />
  </DataLayer>
 // </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**but after doing this on the browser it display nothing no error not a single component that I have created is displayed but when I unwrapped the component it works fine**

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same issue and this is what worked for me …

The component (DataLayer.js) is not returning anything, so you have to change it from this:

```
export const DataLayer = ({initialState, reducer, children}) => {
    <DataLayerContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </DataLayerContext.Provider>
};
```

to this:

```
export const DataLayer = ({ initialState, reducer, children }) => {
  return (
    <DataLayerContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </DataLayerContext.Provider>
  )
};
```